# How to integrate a normal density

Tags: probability-distributions

$Y\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$. And   $Y=\log X$

To find the probability density function of $Y$ and median of $Y$.

How I proceed:
$Y=\log X$

$X=e^Y$

Using distribution function technique

$F(x)=\mathbb{P}(e^y\leq x)=\mathbb{P}(y\leq\log x)$

Now we would integrate minus infinity to $\log X$  for finding cdf and then differentiate it once we will get pdf of $X$.

But how to integrate the density and what about median??

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your question, and check for spelling / typos.

Comment: You don't need to integrate. Instead, you compute $f(x)$ by taking the derivative on both sides and using chain's rule. For more information, check log-normal distribution at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution.

Answer (score 0):

It has no direct expression of x but could be expressed using Q function and the PDF is: $f_{X}(x)={1\over{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}x}e^{-{(lnx-\mu)^{2}}\over{2\sigma^{2}}}$